# Magento - update subtotal while runtime onepage checkout

Tags: magento, refresh, checkout

a customer is in checkout. while the standard checkout progresses i want to renew the subtotal of the checkout session, the payment and the preview steps cause private rules for each customer group. I tried out to set the price via save shipping observer but it doesn't work (the subtotal in preview didn't change and the payment moduls are using the same price as before.. I understand.. the HTML was load before and the steps are only hidden)

Is there any way to refresh the subtotal and the onepagecheckout without loosing the current step ?

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the step you are doing this on, find the save action and add:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
```

To the code before the response.

Works a treat.